# Simplifying ICommand/RelayCommand in a MVVM approach

Tags: mvvm, icommand

I'm pushing myself to make the applications I write simpler, and I've taken some steps to do that, but I'm left with an interesting problem that doesn't at all feel like it would be unique to me. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

I have a ViewModel that keeps a collection of model objects. The view is a ListView that displays all of the objects in the collection. The model objects have all the logic in them to manipulate them. Inside the ListView row for each item I have a button, and that button needs to be wired to call a method on the model object.

To get this to work I need to add a command binding, but to the parent window data context, that passes a parameter of the model object in the row, all so that model object can be used inside the ViewModel (the parent window data context) to call the method on the model object  that's being passed in.

This seems really much more complex than it needs to be. I'm willing to throw out anything I've done already, there are no sacred cows, I just want this to be done in a simpler method that will be easy to look back on in a year and figure out what I was doing.

Comment: You can use a Binding with a RelativeSource that specifies the parent Window and then the property DataContext.MyCommand.

Comment: Why don't your models create a command binding that is invoked directly by the button in the model's view?

Comment: I thought about doing that too, but as much as I am comfortable embedding business logic into my models, using parts of the .NET libraries from System.Windows (DependencyObject - so I would be able to bind) and System.Windows.Input (ICommand/RoutedCommand) just seems wrong to have in a model object.

Answer (score 0):

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
    Path=DataContext.MyCommand}
```

Comment: That's precisely what I would do if I were to just implement it, but my question isn't on how to do this, it's is there a simpler way that isn't so obtuse.

Comment: You could write a markup extension to simplify the expression of said binding.

Comment: I'm attempting that right now, but ideally I'd want the markup extension to be able to to access the object directly. Something along the lines of:

`Command={app:CustomExtension Object=CurrentObject, MethodName=MethodName}`

I'm struggling to get that to work though.

Comment: I ended up creating a custom DelegateCommand class (based on the Prism one) that inherited from DependencyObject and declared the properties as dependency properties. Then I bound to the Command property on the button directly using a custom converter.

Comment: @Andrew Hi. could you put some sample about your las solution ?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez Interestingly enough, I had to rip all of that code out and throw away the button on the ListView altogether. I ran into a memory leak because the binding between the button and the command wasn't being disposed so my ListView would keep references to all of the old rows that had been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a presenter class in your ViewModel for the model objects and have a collection of those.  You can then put the ICommand property on those instead and pass a reference to the method you want to call in the parent datacontext.

Perhaps something like the following:

```
public class ModelPresenter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model _model;

    public ModelPresenter(Model model, Action<Model> parentAction)
    {
        _model = model
        _action = parentAction;
    }

    public ICommand MyAction
    {
        get { return new RelayCommand(() => _parentAction(_model)); }
    }

    ...
}
```

It also sounds like you might be binding to Properties of your model your view.  You shouldn't do this as it can cause a memory leak if your models aren't implementing INotifyPropertyChanged (see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416/en-us).

Comment: I am binding directly to the model, but I opted to enforce INotifyPropertyChanged on all of my model elements to get this done.